# Sort documents in collections while fetching

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java, spring-data-mongodb

I have a collection called at MongoDB called resource.
It has the following documents:

```
{ "_id" : "Abb.e", "_class" : "Resource", "resourceEmail" : "test1@test.com" }
{ "_id" : "Dasd.tt", "_class" : "Resource","resourceEmail" : "test2@test.com" }
{ "_id" : "Bbb.rr", "_class" : "Resource", "resourceEmail" : "test3@test.com" }
```

At Java code,I list them as follows:

```
 MongoOperations mongoOperations = mongoConfiguration.getMongoTemplate();
  List<Resource> resourceList = mongoOperations.findAll(Resource.class);
  return resourceList;
```

How could I fetch these documents sorted by ID !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you're using Spring Data, you could use a Query object to query all documents in the colletion and sort the results.

```
MongoOperations mongoOperations = mongoConfiguration.getMongoTemplate();
Query q = new Query().with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "_id"));
List<Resource> resourceList = mongoOperations.find(q, Resource.class);
return resourceList;
```

Of course that you could iterate the list of results and sort it manually, or even use Collection.sort method, but I think if you have an index in the property that you're using to sort, it's faster to mongodb sort the results.

Comment: When using PagingAndSortingRepository, you can also use `List<T> findAll(Sort sort);` to query all objects and sort the result.

Answer (score 2):

Should be something like this:

```
 MongoOperations mongoOperations = mongoConfiguration.getMongoTemplate();
  List<Resource> resourceList = mongoOperations.findAll(Resource.class).sort({'_id' : 1});
  return resourceList;
```

You need to append `.sort({'_id' : 1})` for ascending order
or `.sort({'_id' : -1})` for descending order.

---

For Java:

```
.sort( new BasicDBObject( "_id" , 1 ) )
```

---

Solution from *echo*:

```
DBCursor dbCursor = mongoOperations.getCollection(RESOURCE_COLLECTION_NAME).find().sort(new BasicDBObject("_id", 1)); 
List<DBObject> dbObjects = dbCursor.toArray(); 
List<Map> items = new ArrayList<Map>(dbCursor.length()); 
for (DBObject dbObject : dbObjects) { 
 Map map = dbObject.toMap(); 
 items.add(dbObject.toMap()); 
}
```

Comment: I am afraid that I didn't find this "sort" method. I use :   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.M5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
      <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.3</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: That helped me.However I couldn't find such a method called sort as you mentioned.

Comment: I found the sort method by the following way and I used your sort methodology:DBCursor dbCursor = mongoOperations.getCollection(RESOURCE_COLLECTION_NAME).find().sort(new BasicDBObject("_id", 1));
      List<DBObject> dbObjects = dbCursor.toArray();
      List<Map> items = new ArrayList<Map>(dbCursor.length());
      for (DBObject dbObject : dbObjects) {
        Map map = dbObject.toMap();
        items.add(dbObject.toMap());
      }

Comment: I was wondering is there any other easier way to fetch directly a list instead of map.As I need to convert this map later to List<Resources> !

Comment: please update your post with the piece of code I posted to use the sort you suggested to accept your answer.