# mongodb read from last to first java program with pagination

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to read data from last to first by java program
The following code will give first 10 records
DBCursor cursor = coll.find().skip(0).limit(5);
It give 0,1,2,3,4
But i need 9,8,7,6,5  on first pagination
at next pagination i need 4,3,2,1,0 
How to do that in java?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this issue, [Sort documents in collections while fetching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895876/sort-documents-in-collections-while-fetching)

Apply the sort with -1 to sort in reverse order against the filed and apply the limit. 
.sort({'_id' : -1})

Or Alternatively.

Using Java.

Use the DBCursor.toArray() put the result into the list and use Collections.reverse(list) and apply the pagination.